Third-party SDK's privacy report are not shown when 'Generate Privacy Report' button tapped
I am developing a flutter app, In order to publish in appstore, In Xcode 15, when performing an Archive build and clicking the 'Generate Privacy Report' button, it is believed that the app creates a PrivacyReport PDF file by inspecting the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file used by the Third-party SDKs within the app. However, upon testing, it appears that only the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file from the app itself is included in the generated PDF, and the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file from Third-party SDKs is not being included.
But I can see the privacy manifest file is available in pods directory.
Also tried to add the pod in XCode -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content and make it "Embed without signing"/ "Embed & Sign" but the build failed everytime as flutter do the project management in different way.
How can I solve it, please help.

Faiaz Rahman!
flutter pub cache repair

happy coding :)
